# Get "Grouped Product" URL, given single product ID

Tags: php, magento, product, catalog

Given the following basic code (which is called from a CMS page):

```
<?php
    $id = $this->getProductId();
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);

    $price=$product->getFinalPrice();
    $name=$product->getName();
    $url=$product->getUrlPath();
?>

<p><a href="<?php echo $url; ?>" title="<?php echo $name; ?>" ><?php echo $name; ?> - &pound;<?php echo $this->helper('tax')->getPrice($product, $product->getFinalPrice(), true) ?></a></p>
```

If the product is part of a product group and not visible individually, I need to retrieve the group URL, not the product URL.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to do this?

--- EDIT ---

Tim has rightly pointed out that a product can be in multiple groups at the same time, therefore I revise my question:

Does anyone know of a way to test if a product does belong to a group and if so, is it possible to retrieve the URLs of those groups?

Comment: Single products can be part or grouped product and standalone product at the same time. So I'd say no way.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
    ->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', array('eq' => 'grouped'));
foreach ($products as $product) {
    $associatedProducts = $product->getTypeInstance(true)->getAssociatedProducts($product);
    // Do something with $associatedProducts
```